# Error: Account allocation failed: RPC response error -32002

Tags: solana-program, cli

```
Error: Account allocation failed: RPC response error -32002 Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found
```

I got this error deploting the program in devnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem installing this solana version:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.13.5/install)"
```

I forgot that the versions for testnet and mainet and devnet go separately, so please look at that detail in the official solana github page, release section